# Sencha cmd build native fails after upgrading to version 5

Tags: ios, sencha-touch, sencha-cmd

I had a sencha touch application for which I packaged it to run natively on mobile, I followed all the steps mentioned in sencha docs in [Native Packaging for Mobile Devices](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/guide/native_packaging) and in [Packaging Native iOS Applications](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/guide/native_provisioning), I built the application using the command `sencha app build native` using `sencha cmd version 4` and completed the provisioning and got the certificate and I copied the application on my iPhone and everything was fine, now there's an update in the application to be made and I have upgraded sencha cmd to version 5, now when I run the build native command I get the following error:

```
BUILD FAILED

[ERR] java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: STBuild is no longer supported in Cmd 5. Please use the cordova or phonegap packager for device packaging.

[ERR]   at org.apac

[ERR] he.tools.ant.TaskAdapter.execute(TaskAdapter.java:154)
```

What does it mean that STBuild is no longer supported? I checked the [docs of sencha cmd 5](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/cmd/intro_to_cmd.html) and here is what's written about packaging:

> Native Packaging: Native packaging to convert a Sencha Touch application into a first-class, mobile application that has access to device functionality and can be distributed in App Stores.

I can't imagine that native build was supported in version 4 and now not supported in version 5.

I am running this on Mac OS X 10.9.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sencha Cmd 5 did drop support for STBuild - it is now recommended you use PhoneGap or Cordova for your hybrid packaging needs. [See this article](http://www.sencha.com/blog/leveraging-phonegap-within-sencha-touch/) for more information as it's really simple to setup.

Also see this thread: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?287378-Mobile-Packager-Changes-in-Sencha-Cmd-5.0